# Need regex help or alternative

Tags: regex

As the question says, I need help with a regex pattern or an alternative.

I have strings that look like the following;

```
"House.Rooms(3).Kitchen(1)"
"House.Kitchen("20.20 feet").Rooms(3).Wc(1)"
```

What I need is a regex pattern that can match the strings above. Think of the strings as programming syntax.

So the above strings are valid, but not: `House .Kitchen("20.20 feet"). Rooms(3).   Wc(1)`.
Spaces are allowed only within double or single quotes.

Currently I have the following regex pattern `/@[0-9a-zA-Z._(,)@]+/` but this does not match strings that have spaces inside them or any other character that isn't defined in the regex.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why? Are you trying to read some kind of source code of an app?

Comment: Its not source code, its a query language, basically external developers can query our database without allowing them to issue sql commands directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should match the strings. I haven't made any capture groups, as you only specify that you want to match the strings, not capture any of the content.

```
^(?:\w+(?:\((?:\d+|".*?")\))?(?:\.|$))+$
```

"Exploded" version, for easier reading:

```
^               # Start of line
  (?:             # Start of group used for repeating
    \w+             # Valid strings (House, Rooms, Kitchen etc.)
    (?:             # Start of optional group containing parenthesis and parameters
      \(              # Literal open parenthesis
      (?:             # Start of group containing parameters
        \d+             # Numbers
        |               # or
        ".*?"           # String/stuff inside quotes
      )               # End of parameter group
      \)              # Literal close parenthesis
    )?              # End of optional group containing parenthesis and parameters
    (?:             # Start of group requiring string to end with a dot or EOL
      \.              # Literal dot
      |               # or
      $               # Must be EOL
    )               # End of group requiring string to end with dot or EOL
  )+              # End of group (repeat 1 or more times)
$               # EOL
```

## [Live version](http://rubular.com/r/eAehn3g5ee)